# AWS, Credential must have exactly 5 slash-delimited elements,

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

During executing `eb init` on Ubuntu 16.04 I faced an error `Credential must have exactly 5 slash-delimited elements, e.g. keyid/date/region/service/term,`.

I understand that my `keyid` has slashes but they must be there, key was provided by AWS and it is generated. I have no idea how to skip this validation. As I know on MAC this problem is not present.

How can I deal with this error? thanks

Comment: In may case I was using access_key as secret_key and secrect_key as access_key :D

Comment: @Adiii this should be an accepted answer LOL helped me alot

Comment: @Moshe haha then I think it's not bad idea to post as an answer :D

Comment: @Adiii go ahead, I'll upvote as it helped me.

Answer (score 31):

An AWS Access Key ID does **not** have any slashes.  It is comprised of uppercase ASCII letters only, and begins with `AKIA...` or `ASIA...`.

One possible explanation is that you have transposed your access key ID with the accompanying secret access key, which does often have slashes.

> Access keys consist of an access key ID (for example, `AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE`) and a secret access key (for example, `wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY`).
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys

If you have indeed transposed these values in your configuration, you should deactivate these credentials and create new ones before proceeding, because you may have inadvertently exposed your secret key.

Answer (score 23):

In my case, I was using `access_key` as `secret_key` and `secrect_key` as `access_key`.

So better to double-check the secret.

Also access key should not contain any special character. Plus one easy to identify the access key is to looking into prefix of the key.

> The access key begins with the prefix `ASIA`, otherwise it beings with `AKIA`. All random looking ID’s on AWS have their own 4 letter prefixes that identify what they are.

[aws_security_credential_formats](https://summitroute.com/blog/2018/06/20/aws_security_credential_formats/)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I was also using them in opposite order, silly me 

Answer (score 3):

i have environmental variables for access id and secret key, i had them interchanged, that was the issue, once i set those correctly it works

Answer (score 0):

In my case, env keys were lowercase. Making them uppercase solved my issue

`aws_access_key_id` -> `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`

`aws_secret_access_key` -> `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`